# Create Request Data Classes with Different Request Type

Tags: java, android, json, request, retrofit

I am using retrofit and I need to pass different request data classes in request for different api. Parent class will be different but child can be different at runtime.

Here are different sample of request :

- first Sample

  { 
     "header":{ 
        "version":"string",
        "locale":"string",
     },
     "body":{ 
        "employee":{ 
           "id":"string",
           "password":"string"
        }
     }
  }
- Second Sample

  { 
     "header":{ 
        "version":"string",
        "locale":"string",
     },
     "body":{
        "worker":{ 
           "name":"string",
           "surname":"string"
        }
     }
  }

I have created different header, body and user classes and trying to figure out how I can create dynamic request.

Comment: You can create such thing by java generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the below example how you can achieve this dynamically:

First we create `RequestHeader` class containing `version` & `locale` keys (I've used Gson to serialize the variables).

**RequestHeader.java**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class RequestHeader {
    @SerializedName("version")
    private String version;
    @SerializedName("locale")
    private String locale;

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }
}
```

We're having dynamic child class that can be anything, so that we create Generic Base class containing "body" parameter as below:

**RequestContainer.java**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class RequestContainer<T> {
    @SerializedName("header")
    private RequestHeader requestHeader;
    @SerializedName("body")
    private T body;

    public RequestHeader getRequestHeader() {
        return requestHeader;
    }

    public void setRequestHeader(RequestHeader requestHeader) {
        this.requestHeader = requestHeader;
    }

    public T getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(T body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

So, now here we can take any dynamic child at run time we want.

Providing API endpoint would something be like (I.e Employee):

```
@POST("someapi")
public Call<SomeResponseClass> saveEmployee(@Body RequestContainer<EmployeeDto>);
```

where `EmployeeDto` would like below:

**EmployeeDto.java**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class EmployeeDto {
    @SerializedName("employee")
    private Employee employee;

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public class Employee {
        @SerializedName("id")
        private String id;
        @SerializedName("password")
        private String password;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
}
```